# .split (regex) behave as in always global scan

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am experiencing a problem with `.split` native function while using it in pair with regex scan.

lets take as an example this situation:

```
var my_string = 'href=/Something/Something_else?=Something';
```

now, i am using this piece of code to split above string:

```
var parts = my_string.split(/=/);
```

By the looking at `console.log` of `parts` it seems that `.split` command created an `array` of 3 items:

- `href`
- `/Something/Something_else?`
- `Something`

What i need is an array of 2 items:

- `href`
- `/Something/Something_else?=Something`

From what i understand, unless `g` (global) flag is casted on regex pattern, it should split only after first found occurrence of `=` (equal) sign.

Is it possible to use this regex pattern `/=/` instead of `/=/g` to achieve exatcly that? or it has to be done in some other way?

Comment: You may try with `s.match(/^([^=]*)=([^]*)/)` and then access Group 1 and 2. `g` is always enabled by default with `split`.

Comment: IndexOf() then split the string in 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `=(.*)` as regexp and limit the results using the second argument

```js
var my_string = 'href=/Something/Something_else?=Something';
var parts = my_string.split(/=(.*)/, 2);
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: More better `my_string.split(/=(.*)/, 2);`

Comment: Thanks @revo. Edited it in!

Answer (score 1):

Use IndexOf() then split the string in 2:

```js
var my_string = 'href=/Something/Something_else?=Something';

var index = my_string.indexOf('=');

var result = [my_string.substring(0, index), my_string.substring(index+1)]

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could lookup the first ocurrance of `=` and split the string yourself.

```js
const 
  my_string = 'href=/Something/Something_else?=Something',
  firstEquals = my_string.indexOf('='),
  parts = [
    my_string.substr(0, firstEquals),
    my_string.substr(firstEquals+1)
  ];

console.log(parts);
```